Setting a breakpoint on CreateFile() API in WinDbg
I have set up WinDbg for hybrid (user mode to kernel mode) debugging.
In the user mode application, I am calling CreateFile() with certain parameters. I want to break at the CreateFile() call in context of the user mode process, and trace its execution from there.
I tried searching for the CreateFile symbol with the x command. The issue is that x nt!*CreateFile* cannot find the respective symbol. Out of the bunch of symbols it lists, the closest I could find was nt!NtCreateFile, which appears to have a different signature, and presumably an internal API.
Why is the CreateFile() symbol missing in WinDbg?

Because no such symbol. Exist CreateFileW and CreateFileA . And it exported by kernel32.dll and kernelbase.dll . Not by ntoskrnl

@RbMm that should be posted as an answer instead of a comment

Function names in Windows
You can search for Microsoft Windows API functions using the search terms "MSDN <function>". If you do so, this brings you to CreateFileA(). That website tells you that the function is defined in fileapi.h.
Look inside fileapi.h (find it on your local machine, e.g. using Everything), you'll find these lines:
#ifdef UNICODE
#define CreateFile  CreateFileW
#else
#define CreateFile  CreateFileA
#endif // !UNICODE

So, CreateFile() is just an alias for either CreateFileA() or CreateFileW(), depending on whether you compile for ANSI or Unicode.
You'll find many functions which are redirected like that and have the ...A() and ...W() naming convention. That's outlined by MS on Unicode in the Windows API and they explain the conventions using another example.
Debugging
On the same website, there's a section called Requirements, which says
Header     fileapi.h (include Windows.h)
Library    Kernel32.lib
DLL        Kernel32.dll

So the breakpoints can be set with
0:001> bp kernel32!CreateFileA
0:001> bp kernel32!CreateFileW

But your x approach also works, if you search in all modules, like
0:001> x *!CreateFileA
00007ff8`23dc1320 KERNELBASE!CreateFileA (void)
00007ff8`25fa4e90 KERNEL32!CreateFileA (CreateFileA)

With both breakpoints (A and W) set, you should find the function:
0:001> g
Breakpoint 1 hit
KERNEL32!CreateFileW:
00007ff8`25fa4ea0 ff251af40500    jmp     qword ptr [KERNEL32!_imp_CreateFileW (00007ff8`260042c0)] ds:00007ff8`260042c0={KERNELBASE!CreateFileW (00007ff8`23dc1410)}

Module load order
as followed up in comments
When should the kernel!* functions be available? Very early, typically at the initial breakpoint already. The first 4 modules loaded are your app, ntdll, kernel32 and kernelbase, if you don't debug a so called native DLL, which tries to get rid of as many dependencies as possible.
ModLoad: 00007ff7`bf830000 00007ff7`bf866000   YourApp.exe
ModLoad: 00007ffc`dfdd0000 00007ffc`dffc8000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffc`df8b0000 00007ffc`df971000   C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ffc`dd970000 00007ffc`ddc6d000   C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll

and then, depending on the programming language, e.g. C++
ModLoad: 00007ffc`88280000 00007ffc`8828f000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140_1D.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffc`72710000 00007ffc`7273e000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140D.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffc`6b2e0000 00007ffc`6b3c2000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140D.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffc`00430000 00007ffc`00651000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ucrtbased.dll
ModLoad: 0000020a`14190000 0000020a`143b1000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ucrtbased.dll
(4ac.32c): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x30:
00007ffc`dfea0820 cc              int     3

Windows Internals 7 Part 1 says (chapter "Early process initialization")

In newer versions of Windows, the loader instead builds a dependency map ahead of time, with specific nodes that describe a single DLL and its dependency graph, building out separate nodes that can
be loaded in parallel.

So the load order may even vary between runs, but I haven't seen that for these most basic DLLs.
If you really don't see kernelbase or kernel32 yet, you have the following options:

wait until the module is loaded, e.g. with sxe ld kernel* (enable exception on load of a module, filtering for kernel)
set an unresolved breakpoint using bu


Why is the same symbol exported twice, both from Kernel32 and Kernelbase?

Kernel32 is a stub which redirects to kernelbase   which has the implementation look at the disassembly of kernel32 in the answer  which simply jumps

Something weird is going on. When I ran x *!CreateFileA yesterday, it did return those two symbols. When I am trying out the same command today, it returns nothing. If I shoot x KERNEL32!*, it says Couldn't resolve 'x kernel32'. Any ideas?

@TracyMcDowell: What does lm m kernel say?

From lm, as far as I can see, kernel32/kernelbase is not loaded. I can see win32k/win32kfull/win32kbase/nt there, among others. lm m kernel returns an empty list

Viruses are out of question. It's a test program that I wrote I am debugging right now. I swear x *!CreateFileA worked before, produced the exact same outout as yours. I am thinking if WinDbg is "broken" somehow. Also, kernel32.dll  is listed in the output of dumpbin /imports.

I don't know what just happened. I disconnected/reconnected windbg from/to the debugee machine. Then issued .reload command. Now both kernel32/kernelbase appear in lm output.

@TracyMcDowell Processes are self-initializing. If you break early enough no modules (other than ntdll.dll) have been loaded. That could be the issue you're observing.

@IInspectable Probably you're right. I have seen just nt at some point. Then nt alongwith a bunch of other modules. And finally, randomly at some point, kernel* magically appeared

Do you have any idea at which point kernel* modules get loaded?

No, but I'm pretty sure you can set a breakpoint on module load in WinDbg.

I added a section about the load order.

@IInspectable: sure, sxe ld *, but since I see kernel32 already loaded at the initial breakpoint,, that shouldn't be necessary. Or one could set an unresolved breakpoint using bu.
